# DB get Current DB Name

Tags: db2

I need to write a SQL Script in DB2 and I have to make a constraint in order for this SQL to run only on some specific DBs.

I looked online for solutions but I did not find any.

Does anybody know a way to get the name of the current connected DB?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
Select CURRENT_SERVER from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

The database name can be retrieved via the special register `CURRENT_SERVER`.

Comment: Hi data_henrik, your SQL seems to work. I only wonder if it will bring back the accurate Name on other DB. I also found the DB_Name Column in SYSIBMADM->APPLICATIONS->DB_NAME meanwhile. Thank you! I will  mark your answer as useful :).

Comment: My feedback will be recorded and it'll be displayed soon. Thank you once again :)

Comment: CURRENT_SERVER throws an error in DB2 v9. (z/os)

CURRENT SERVER  works though