# Equivalent of Oracle SYS.GLOBAL_NAME or MS-SQL SYS.DATABASES for IBM DB2/iSeries Databases

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, db2

I'm currently writing a program that allows a user to choose between MSSQL, Oracle, DB2, and iSeries databases. The application is built in VB.NET and selecting a "database type" is mapped to radio buttons. When the user clicks a radio button it calls an instance of each providers' DataSourceEnumerator. From the information it gets it fills a ServerName combo box with the server names the enumerator detects and the user may select.

I wanted to keep this same functionality moving forward throughout the application. So for the next combo box the user needs to select a database on that server. For MSSQL I execute the query,

`SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master', 'tempdb', 'model', 'msdb');`

And Oracle I use,

`select * from SYS.global_name`.

This works exactly how I intended because the results are added into a combo box for the user to select from. What I'm having trouble with is finding a query for IBM DB2 and/or iSeries that could provide the same functionality. I've read through documentation for both and I can't find what I'm looking for. Is this sort of query not possible in DB2/iSeries? And if it is what would be the correct query to use?

Comment: Does this help: [DB get current DB Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676027/db-get-current-db-name) ? Seems to work in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=9aae782b8b3f4613c2c90d882b335d3e).

Comment: @PonderStibbons Hm this is close but not exactly what I'm looking for. It seems to show the name of the database you're currently connected to. But what I'm trying to do is to provide a list of the database names as a means to connect. The data source enumerator gives the server names then I have a database combo box that should list the available databases. When the user selects both then it builds a connection string to a specific database.

Comment: Maybe [sysdatabase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/cattab/src/tpc/db2z_sysibmsysdatabasetable.html). ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retireve iASP RDB name to specify it in jdbc url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55530238/retireve-iasp-rdb-name-to-specify-it-in-jdbc-url)

Comment: @mao I'll have to update in a little while for this solution because I have to remote into a client machine to test. The current answer works for the DB2 part of my question, hopefully this satisfies the iSeries portion as well!

Comment: @SMor I looked into that awhile back, but for some reason there isn't a sysdatabase table

Answer (score 0):

Db2 for LUW:
List all active databases under the same instance managing the currently connected database.
Not active local databases are invisible for this query.

```
SELECT DB_NAME FROM TABLE(SNAP_GET_DB(NULL))
```

You must have an appropriate authority to use this [SNAP_GET_DB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056479.html) function.

Comment: The documentation says this table function is deprecated is that a non-issue?

Comment: No at least for all Db2 for LUW versions at the moment. Nobody knows, what will happen with this function id Db2 vNext. But now it's the only function I know, which lists all local active databases via a connection to one of them. You must write an external C / Java function otherwise.